# confidence interval based on sequentional sampling

Tags: python, sampling, normal-distribution, confidence-interval

When I want 100 sample sequentially from N(1,2) and estimate the means and std sequentially I can do it like:

```
sample = np.random.normal(1,2,(100, 1))
sample_mean = []
for i,_ in enumerate(sample):
    sample_mean.append(sample[:i+1,:].ravel().mean())
    sample_std.append(sample[:i+1,:].ravel().std())
```

But if I want to compute the confidence intervals for these sequential samples how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can calculate the CI of a sample mean as [sampleMean +/- tstat * std/sqrt(n)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_interval#Basic_steps)

and CI of a sample standard deviation as a square root of [( (sampleSize-1)*std^2/chisq(a/2),  (sampleSize-1)*std^2/chisq(1-a/2) )](http://www.milefoot.com/math/stat/ci-variances.htm).

Here is an sample:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
from scipy.stats import chi2

n_series = 100
sample = np.random.normal(0,1,n_series)
sample_mean, sample_std = [], []
sample_mean_CI, sample_std_CI = [], []
alpha = 0.1 # e.g. alpha = 0.1 for 90-percent CI, alpha=0.05 for 95-percent CI

def mean_div(std, n, alpha): return stats.t.isf(alpha/2, n) * (std/np.sqrt(n))
def mean_ci(xbar, std, n, alpha): 
    div = mean_div(std, n, alpha)
    return (xbar - div, xbar + div)

def std_lower(std, n, alpha): return np.sqrt(((n-1)*std**2)/chi2.isf(alpha/2, n-1))
def std_upper(std, n, alpha): return np.sqrt(((n-1)*std**2)/chi2.isf(1-alpha/2, n-1))
def std_ci(std, n, alpha): return (std_lower(std, n, alpha), std_upper(std, n, alpha))

for i,_ in enumerate(sample):
    x = sample[:i+1]
    xbar = x.mean()
    std = x.std()
    sample_mean.append(xbar)
    sample_std.append(std)
    sample_mean_CI.append(mean_ci(xbar, std, i+1, alpha))
    sample_std_CI.append(std_ci(std, i+1, alpha))
    
# check for convergence for the whole series
print(sample_mean_CI[-1])
print(sample_std_CI[-1])
```

One can change the number of data series and/or the mean and std parameters of normal distribution to experiment with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with OpenTURNS. The following code computes asymptotic bilateral confidence intervals on the parameters (mean and standard deviation) with confidence level 0.9.

```
import numpy as np
import openturns as ot
sample = np.random.normal(1,2,(100, 1))
confidence_level = 0.9
sample_mean_ci = []
sample_std_ci = []
nor = ot.NormalFactory() # class that fits a Normal distribution on the data
for i in range(1, len(sample)):
    estimated_params = nor.buildEstimator(sample[:i+1,:]).getParameterDistribution()
    ci = estimated_params.computeBilateralConfidenceInterval(confidence_level)
    sample_mean_ci.append([ci.getLowerBound()[0], ci.getUpperBound()[0]])
    sample_std_ci.append([ci.getLowerBound()[1], ci.getUpperBound()[1]])
```